# Why my CSS is not overridden?

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
.x-container img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.content img{
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class="x-container span-18">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="image.jpg" id="disneland-img">
    </div>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
```

I have html like above. I was expecting `clear:both` in `.content img` will override `float:left` of `.x-container img`, but it is not.

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: Your image will be both floating AND not allowing other floating elements to be positioned beside it. Your definitions will not override one another.

You may wish to set the clear property for the h2, pheraps?

Comment: **Different** CSS properties don't override each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` and `clear` are two distinct css declarations. They don't override each other. (Although they are relating to/influencing each other of course.) If you want to override your `float:left` of your first class you can simply write:

```
.content img{
    float:none;
}
```

Clearing the float is another thing, you need to use the `clear` on a sibling element, or put an `overflow:auto|hidden` on the parent element or apply the so called "clear-fix" method.

```
.clearfix:after {
     content:"";
     display:table;
     clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph! Direct answer!

Answer (score 1):

user clearfix class direct on image , that will do all the job
put clearfix class on div with content class.

```
<div class="x-container span-18">
    <div class="content clearfix ">
    <img src="image.jpg" id="disneland-img">
    </div>
<h2>Hello</h2>
</div>

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/TVm6K/

Answer (score 0):

THis should fix it.

```
.x-container img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.x-container h2 {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should specify float:inherit in .content class

```
.content img{
    float:inherit;
    clear:both;
}
```

Because float attribute by default is set to none.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp